# Group by LastActivityDate and different notetext

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a problem in SQL, Writing SQL where two result set like

```
Select 
  CustID, B, C, D, Max(LastActivityDate) as  LastDateModified, NoteAdded 
from (
      Select 
         CustID,B,C,D, Max(LastActivityDate) as  LastDateModified, NoteAdded 
       from tblA group by CustID,B,C,D, NoteAdded
      UNION
      Select
         CustId,B,C,D, Max(LastActivityDate) as  LastDateModified, NoteAdded 
       from tblB group by CustID,B,C,D, NoteAdded
) as tblC 
group by CustID,B,C,D, LastDateModified, NoteAdded
```

I am getting two rows as `NoteAdded` is different but I need the one record depend on `LastActivityDate`. But as `NoteAdded` is different when grouping by both getting two records.

Here is the image with sample records as requested.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What if you remove `NoteAdded` from the `SELECT` list and `Group By` list of the outer query? (Or just flat out remove `NoteAdded` from the inner queries?)

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @DVT we need Notes added in grid. So need to show the last activity record with comments or notes

Comment: @qazifarhan We need source data and desire output. And include your data as text not image. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a **[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** and getting the top 1 per partition, ordered by `LastDateModified desc`.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partiton by CustID, B, C, D
          order by LastDateModified desc
    )
  from (
    select CustID, B, C, D, LastDateModified, NoteAdded
    from tblA
    union all
    select CustID, B, C, D, LastDateModified, NoteAdded
    from tblB
    ) as u
  )
select CustID, B, C, D, LastDateModified, NoteAdded
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for quick solution. One thing your sql was showing an error 
its a minor dont know why but when changed by this it works

(in capital letters no space)

row_number() over (PARTITION BY

Comment: @qazifarhan Ahh you're right, I had a typo there. `paritition` should have been `partition` without the extra i